# How do I display blank dropdown values upon loading an Angular form?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have built a form in Angular using `ReactiveFormsModule` that uses primarily dropdown boxes via the `<select>` element.

Each `<select>` is databound to an Angular FormControl instance; upon loading the webpage the dropdown menus are automatically loaded with a value from a REST API call, but what I want is for them to display a blank entry until the user manually clicks the dropdown and selects one of the options below.

Is there a way to do using the `ReactiveFormsModule`?

Comment: The default is to show the `select` field as empty, so if it's not empty, there is something in the code that you are using to load the form. Could you share the HTML, FormControls creation and how you assign values to the FormControl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add an `option` in the `select` directly in the template. If you want, you could also use `*ngIf` on that option to remove it once you receive your data. Something like this maybe:

```
<mat-select>
  <mat-option *ngIf="!data" [value]="null">
    Loading...
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```